# Redis python cannot create local server within Docker

Tags: python, docker, redis, continuous-integration

So I have this setup where within a Docker container I need to run a python library test suite (designed for my company) and in my test suite for our Redis Connector, the creation of a `locaclhost:6379` redis server is denied.

> redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.

The `test_redis.py` passes in an open environment with `nose` but fails in the Continuous Integration (within Docker).

**Does Docker block all `localhost` services or am I using a wrong approach ?**

**Setup**

> Ubuntu 17.04
>
> Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802

Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.3.14

MAINTAINER ... <...@fifty-five.com>

WORKDIR /app

RUN which conda && which python && which pip && apt update && apt install -y build-essential libblas-dev liblapack-dev libatlas-base-dev gfortran
RUN conda install -y numpy && conda install -y scikit-learn && conda install -y scipy
RUN apt update && apt install -y libmysqlclient-dev
COPY . /app/maids
RUN cd /app/maids/ && pip install -e .
```

Using Makefile build command:

```
test_docker_light_py3: #build_datascience_base3
    docker run -e GCS_BUCKET=${GCS_BUCKET} -e GCS_BUCKET_TEST=${GCS_BUCKET_TEST} -e TEST_DATASET=${TEST_DATASET} -e TEST_DATASET_2=${TEST_DATASET_2} -e DOC_SSH_HOST=${DOC_SSH_HOST} -e DOC_SSH_PATH=${DOC_SSH_PATH} -v $(shell pwd):/app -i -t "${LOCAL_TEST_IMAGE3}" /bin/bash -c "python --version ; pip freeze ; python -m 'nose' -a '!slow' --nologcapture --nocapture --with-coverage --cover-package=maids --with-timer --timer-top-n 10 tests/*.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fairly simple to fix in the end. Indeed, my docker image lacked the `redis-server` tool and didn't provide anything on :6379. The fix was to use a mock for redis-py in my test suite.